# При формировании pdf документа обрезаются строки

Tags: php, pdf

Здравствуйте, проблема выглядит [следующим образом](http://profmodule.ru/ufpdf/pdf_work.php) т.е строки выводятся не полностью. PDF документ формирую с помощью библиотеки ufpdf, модифицированным классом ufpdf2.

```
    <?php
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
define('FPDF_FONTPATH', '/home/a0128085/domains/profmodule.ru/public_html/ufpdf/font/');
include_once('ufpdf2.php');
$pdf = new UFPDF2();
$pdf->Open();
$pdf->SetTitle("Тестовый документ");
$pdf->SetAuthor('Steven Wittens');
$pdf->AddFont('LaudatioC', '', 'laudcn_2.php');
$pdf->AddPage();
$date = date('d.m.y');
$pdf->SetFont('LaudatioC','',10);
$pdf->Cell(100,10,'Комплексное оснащение баров, ресторанов, кафе, пищевых производств и магазинов. Работаем с 1993 г.',15);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Cell(100,10,'Интернет-магазин',15);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Cell(100,10,'Интернет-сайт',15);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Cell(100,10,$date,15);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Cell(100,10,'Предварительный список товаров',15);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Cell(100,10,'Вы можете оформить заказ или получить консультацию по телефону',15);
$pdf->Output(); ?>
```

Кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой, подскажите как решить.

Comment: Неплохо бы приложить ссылку на ufpdf2. По теме - попробуйте в `$pdf->Cell(100,10` исправить 100 на 200

Comment: @Total Pusher, пробовал - не помогает. Отключил класс ufpdf2, остались ufpdf и fpdf библиотеки. Ясно, что решение находится в этих двух файлах, где-то задается принудительный перенос строки или фиксированная длина строки. Вот [ссылка](https://yadi.sk/d/Gf-KM4Ve3T6oJU) на архив с двумя этими файлами

Comment: приложите ссылку на библиотеку. то что я нашел - "родитель" для данной